# Detecting if CarrierService API is available

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

What is the recommended way of detecting if a store has `CarrierService` API available? I.e. it's on the [right plan or billed annually](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/shipping_and_fulfillment/carrierservice#requirements-for-accessing-the-carrierservice-resource).

I noticed attempting to retrieve [a list of carrier services](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/shipping_and_fulfillment/carrierservice#index) could work since it's always empty if a shop cannot use the `CarrierService` API. However, that feels hacky. Apart from that, I can imagine a scenario when this can return empty also for shops with that API available. Is there a better, more reliable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only sure way is to try creating a carrier service. [This API call](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/shipping_and_fulfillment/carrierservice#create) will fail with a specific error message in the response body when the shop doesn't have that feature.

Comment: Thanks, Josh! I think I'll go with this approach.